# Jquery chevron toggle with less

Tags: html, less

```
<div class="data-row data-has-detail">
    ...
</div>
```

After expanding the div class becomes

```
<div class="data-row data-has-detail data-detail-shown">
    ...
</div>
```

I am trying to change the chevron on toggle with css but it doesn't work

```
<div class="btn-actions">
    <span class="show-detail-new toggle-detail text-primary chk-move-down">
        <span class="span-show-details"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-chevron-circle-down"></i></span>
        <span class="span-hide-details"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-chevron-circle-up"></i></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

**less code**

```
.data-has-detail {
  .show-detail-new {
    span.span-show-details {
      display: block;
    }
    span.span-hide-details {
      display: none;
    }
  }
}

.data-has-detail .data-detail-shown {
  .show-detail-new {
    span.span-show-details {
      display: none;
    }
    span.span-hide-details {
      display: block;
    }
  }
}
```

Toggle with css not working

Comment: Unless you are using LESS / SASS, that is not valid CSS.  You cannot "nest" selectors like that.  You'll need to rewrite as `.data-has-detail .show-detail-new span.span-show-details { display: block; }`, etc.

Comment: @cale_b Sorry i am using LESS

Comment: Vini - that's fine, my answer still provides some insights into the issue.  See the section about the spaces between classes .

Comment: I've updated the answer to address LESS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an element has multiple classes, you select them like so:

```
.data-has-detail.data-detail-shown
```

(No space - the space tells it it's a child element, no space says "this element has *both* classes)

**Update - with LESS**

Since you are using LESS, then the primary issue is the one I mentioned about spaces between selectors.  In LESS you solve that with the `&` symbol, like so:

```
.data-has-detail {
    .show-detail-new {
        span.span-show-details {
            display: block;
        }
        span.span-hide-details {
            display: none;
        }
    }

 /** the & will cause it to be ".data-has-detail.data-detail-shown" **/
   &.data-detail-shown {
       .show-detail-new {
           span.span-show-details {
               display: none;
            }
            span.span-hide-details {
                display: block;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As an observation under the heading of "maintainable code", **and for performance**, I'd suggest finding a way to simplify this.  Something like this would be a bit less verbose, and should work:

```
.show-detail-new {
    .span-show-details {
      display: block;
    }
}

.show-detail-new {
    .span-hide-details {
        display: none;
    }
}

.data-detail-shown {
    .span-show-details {
        display: none;
    }
}
.data-detail-shown .span-hide-details {
  display: block;
}
```

(Currently, your selectors blow out into a huge selector when compiled by LESS, so your CSS stylesheet is probably larger than it needs to be:

```
.data-has-detail .data-detail-shown .show-detail-new span.span-show-details {
      display: none;
 }

 .... etc for other rules ...
```